# What should be unit tested when refactoring an existing report?

Tags: unit-testing

I've refactored some middle tier reports that are basically a method that take a bunch of parameters, fetch some stuff from the database, then return the result set. The code within the method is usually simple but I'm never sure how to best write unit tests for them. If a method has 43 parameters then wouldn't it need at least 43 tests to show that the results include the right things? And another 43 to show that it excludes the right things? I've seen bugs that only exist when two specific parameters are used (like searching for users based on name and on start date) so should I test every pair of parameters? It seems like these tests would be either uselessly minimal or wastefully exhaustive.

All the unit test examples I've seen are for really simple methods. So how do you write unit tests for an existing 43 parameter method that you need to refactor without breaking?

**[EDIT]**
The method is used by a web page report that has 43 inputs, so as bad as it is, there's some reason for it. I have to extract the logic of the report from ASP.NET code behind and web controls because it needs to be used as acceptance criteria for some unit tests I'm writing for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you were exaggerating whey saying a Method with 43 parameters! If not, that's just plain wrong, and it'd be the first thing I start to refactor.

You can always test what really matters for you. In your case, you should have created a failing unit test before you do the actual refactoring. It would at first, make sure there is a bug, and once the bug is resolve, will make sure it is working and will remain that way if further refactorings come along.